# Codeigniter: Select from multiple tables

Tags: activerecord, select, codeigniter

How can I select rows from two or more tables?

I'm setting default fields for a form, and I need values from two tables...

My current code reads:

```
    $this->CI->db->select('*');
    $this->CI->db->from('user_profiles');
    $this->CI->db->where('user_id' , $id);
    $user = $this->CI->db->get();
    $user = $user->row_array();
    $this->CI->validation->set_default_value($user);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The example in the User Guide should explain this:

```
$this->db->select('*'); // <-- There is never any reason to write this line!
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

See the whole thing under [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) page in the User Guide.

Comment: The example in the User Guide doesn't seem to produce a field from the second table.  How do you do that?

Comment: * = everything, from all tables available. If it's not showing up you're doing something wrong. Also if you have two fields with the same name in different tables, then only one will show. You need to do `foo as bar` to get `->bar`

Answer (score 12):

Just add the other table to the "->from()" method. Something like:

```
 $this->db->select('t1.field, t2.field2')
          ->from('table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2')
          ->where('t1.id = t2.table1_id')
          ->where('t1.user_id', $user_id);
```

Comment: That will produce broken syntax.

Comment: Not on my end. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That syntax is only supported in php5

Answer (score 8):

I think the question was not so much about joins as how to display values from two different tables - the User Guide doesn't seem to explain this.

Here's my take:

```
    $this->db->select('u.*, c.company, r.description');
    $this->db->from('users u, company c, roles r');
    $this->db->where('c.id = u.id_company');
    $this->db->where('r.permissions = u.permissions');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see. Wasn't sure if a comma delimited string or array with multiple values would be the right syntax. Also wasn't sure about matching them in the where method.

Comment: You can do this if you need the record set: return $this->db->get()->result();

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax is incorrect.
You need to select one record. I have two tables, and I have an id from one table transfer by parameter, and the relation of both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('student')
            ->where('student.roll_no',$id)
            ->join('student_details','student_details.roll_no = student.roll_no')
            ->join('course_details','course_details.roll_no = student.roll_no');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SqlInfo="select a.name, b.data fromtable1 a, table2 b where a.id=b.a_id";
$query = $this->db->query($SqlInfo);
```

---

try this way, you can add a third table named as c and add an 'and' command to the sql command.

Comment: I'm a major noob.  Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: That's not an active record way of running queries.

Comment: based on the documentation, yes it is a way to do JOIN operation in CodeIgniter https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

> // Select From Table 1 All Fields, and From Table 2 one Field or more ....

```
$this->db->select('table1.*, table2.name');
    $this->db->from('table1, table2');
    $this->db->where('table2.category_id = table1.id');
    $this->db->where('table2.lang_id',$id); // your where with variable
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```