# Codeigniter Select data from multiple tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been using this model for getting datafrom only one table

```
function model_employee_all()
 {
  $this->load->database();
  $query = $this->db->get('mytable1');
  return $query->result();
 }
```

How should i configure it to get data from multiple tables such as mytable1 and mytable2, Is there any way to use joins...

Thanks.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774538/codeigniter-select-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->join
```

Please refer the following url
    http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html