# Codeigniter like search in several tables

Tags: codeigniter

Hello stackoverflow community. 
I want to make automatic search, based on article title, to show last news about it. These news can be in one or several tables, we dont know for use. Here it is my code:

```
$search = 'any article title';
$Linkearray = array('title' => $search);
$Linkearray2 = array('text' => $search);
$this->db->or_like($Linkearray);
$this->db->or_like($Linkearray2);
$this->db->from('table1', 'table2');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Then i try to show results on page by next code:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row):
echo $row['title'];
endforeach;
```

The problem is, that it shows search results only from table1. 
If i rewrite a line of code into:

```
$this->db->from('table1, table2');
```

I get an error 1052. If anyone has an idea how to solve it, please share it :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774538/codeigniter-select-from-multiple-tables, just separate table with commas ('table1, table2')?

Comment: thx for your post. but when i try to separate with commas i get 1052 error...i'll check your link precise.

Comment: Could you post your db scheme, and output/echo query? When you are sure that 'pure' sql query return desired results, then you can try to convert it in active record format... i think that one of problems could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509798/codeigniter-column-id-in-order-clause-is-ambiguous (same column names in both tables)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, here is solution:

```
$search = 'some word';
$Linkearray = array('table1.title' => $search,'table2.text' => $search);
$Linkearray2 = array('table2.title' => $search,'table2.text' => $search);
$this->db->or_like($Linkearray);
$this->db->or_like($Linkearray2);
$this->db->from('table1,table2');
$query = $this->db->get();

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row):
echo $row['title'];
endforeach;
```

This way - you will avoid 1052 error, and script will return data from both tables. Query generated in this case is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`table1`, `table2`)
WHERE `table1`.`title` LIKE '%strokes%'
   OR `table2`.`text` LIKE '%strokes%'
   OR `table2`.`title` LIKE '%strokes%'
   OR `table2`.`text` LIKE '%strokes%'
```

However, it will return some duplicated results... Better query, or php manipulation of results... to get desired output.

Answer (score -1):

can you use php function to combine the outputs?
something like...

array_merge($this->db->from('table1'), $this->db->from(table2))